# Publishing Shiny app to shinyapps.io with animation generated with gganimate

Tags: r, shiny, gganimate

I am trying to deploy my Shiny app to shinyapps.io. This app works fine locally, and also the deployment process seems to go well:

[image]

However, when I access the website online, I get an error message:

> An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

Here are my logs:

[image]

Is this a matter of shinyapps.io not being able to run the gifski package?

Comment: Is it possible to try using a different renderer?

Comment: My animation is saved as a gif and the Shiny app loads that gif, so that's why I'm sticking to this renderer. However, do you know what format the other renderer outputs to? I could definitely change the renderer

Comment: You could find more info on the renderer outputs here:https://rdrr.io/github/dgrtwo/gganimate/man/renderers.html It seems only gifski returns a gif(perharps hence the name) except **magick** but still uses gifski. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Yeah the problem I'm having is that except gifski, none of these renderers specify the output format in that documentation

Answer (score 3):

For those encountering this issue, I got it fixed by including `library(gifski)` & `library(png)` in my code. Huge thanks to Josh who helped out [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/publishing-shiny-app-to-shinyapps-io-with-animation-generated-with-gganimate/22526/3)